# PHP: How to check if ANY are located in string?

Tags: php, strpos

I am trying to see if any of a list of items are located in a PHP string. I know how to use `strpos` to test against one item:

```
if (strpos($string, 'abc') !== FALSE) {
```

But, how would I test, for example, if either 'abc' or 'def' appear in the $string?

Comment: preg_match() comes to mind

Comment: Or even looping an array with `foreach`, but the above option is probably more suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string=" fish abc cat";

if (preg_match("/abc|def/", $string) === 1){
echo 'match';
}
```

will echo match if either abc or def is found in the string

Comment: shouldn't do `preg_match("/(abc)|(def)/", $string)` ? im a bit lost with this ... ( or not ( .. this is the question :(

Comment: no brackets needed your not using the matches for anything

Comment: @Bob0t Even if you do need the capture groups, see `/(abc|def)/`. `|` stands for "I separate alternatives", the brackets are there for capturing and is not part of the syntax for alternatives in a list of options to match.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `preg_match()`, you  can't really do that. If you have some sort of delimiter, you can turn it into an array:

```
$string = 'I have abc and jkl and xyz.';
$string_array = explode(' ', $string);
$needed_array = array('abc', 'jkl', 'xyz');

$found = false;
foreach($needed_array as $need){
    if( in_array($need, $string_array) ){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all of your search strings into an array and then loop thru the string that you want to be searched.

```
$items = array('abcs', 'def');

for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++) {
    if(strpos($string, $items[$i]) !== FALSE) {

    }
 }
```